# Django: Any app recommendations for PayPal Adaptive Payments?

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Like the title says, I'm looking for an app which helps me integrate the PayPay Adaptive Payments API with a Django website.

So far I've checked out

- django-paypal (https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal, might work with some modifications)
- django-paypal-adaptive (https://github.com/gmcguire/django-paypal-adaptive)

Unfortunately both seem to be buggy/not anymore maintained, any suggestions for alternatives?
How did you integrate it, custom solution or take one of these apps and update/modify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a couple of ecommerce and *paypal adaptive payment type projects*.

And our usual approach is to use https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal and customize it as needed.

If you are looking at a full fledge ecommerce sites, give satchless and django oscar a spin.

- http://satchless.com/
- http://oscarcommerce.com

I have also gone through the process of looking for good libraries but this is pretty much it. And I think they are good enough as a start point to build your custom work on.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: django-oscar's PayPal extension doesn't support Adaptive payments right now, but this is likely to change soon.  https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal